# regex find first word between spaces after specific word c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have this line:

**abc** *cd_ef_1g* fff

the 'abc' is a fixed value and always there. The fff can change.

I'm now searching for the following word, which is always second, always between whitespaces or tabs, and always after 'abc'.

*cd_ef_1g*

It could be with '_' or '-', or numbers.

I've searched all over, found similar results but not exactly with these conditions (using REGEX in C#).

Please help.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a mere [`s.Split()`](http://ideone.com/pjdJ4n)?

Comment: search for abc plus a whitespace at the beginning, then capture any non-whitespace characters.

Comment: You really just need to learn regex. There are many, many tutorials and sites online that can help with that. Please, help yourself by trying some things out before asking.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, this is no use, as there could be one or more tabs, one or more spaces, etc. I am looking word between spaces.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan, I've asked this question after 2 hrs searching in the web, and trying several regex expressions in online regex editors. Writing 'you just need to learn regex' is useless and insulting. If so, no one should ask anything in this forum, because always 'you just need to learn this and  that and try yourself before asking question'.

Comment: It was not meant to be insulting. It was meant to point out why your question was about to be closed. There is nothing *in your question* that indicates that any of that research was done nor any of those attempts were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, this should be sufficient:

```
abc\s+([\w-]+)\s+fff

abc       # Always before
\s+       # One or more white-space chars
([\w-]+)  # One or more alphanumeric chars ('-' also included)
\s+       # One or more white-space chars
fff       # Always after
```

The captured group is the word sought after.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h6Z4bZ/1)

Comment: Thanks, linden2015, this is what I was looking for. Great help! thank you.